# APIError(code=-2015): Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action for Withdrawal using Binance

Tags: python, api, binance, cryptocurrency

```
def withdraw():
try:
    # name parameter will be set to the asset value by the client if not passed
    result = client.withdraw(
        coin='TRX',
        address='<my trx address>',
        amount=100)
    print(result)
except BinanceAPIException as e:
    print(e)
else:
    print("Success")
```

So after executing above method I am getting an error as `APIError(code=-2015): Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action.`
I have enabled withdrawal permission for my API key , also added IP address in Restricted addresses in binance account, still getting this error , not sure where is the exact issue.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you should remove IP from list to access it from every IP.

Comment: That is the only error message I am getting as exception and no traceback. Above I have given the sample code that I have used for Withdrawal

Comment: 'Restrict access to trusted IPs only (Recommended)' this is mandatory to fill IP addresses in order to enable withdrawal for API key

Comment: which library are you using? does the api key work with other methods?

Comment: Yes, API key is working for other methods such as get account info, buy, sell.. but for withdraw it is not working as we need authorized IP addresses, I am using python-binance for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now I have added my public IP address in 'Restrict access to trusted IPs only (Recommended)' column of Binance API key management , and it is working as expected